# How to get the ID of a fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

First of all, I followed [this tutorial](http://arvid-g.de/12/android-4-actionbar-with-tabs-example) to create an activity with an actionbar+tabs. What this implementation does is that it has a fragment_container (just a linear layout) in the main_activity layout and it replaces it with a fragment depending on what tab is selected.

Now, I'm trying to add some [fragment-to-activity communication](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html#Deliver) but I'm getting a nullpointerexemption.

Here's my code:

```
com.mypackage.MAPFragment map_ =
(com.mypackage.MAPFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
map_.ActivityToMapMethod();
```

The **MAPFragment** fragment inflates a xml layout that has a mapView with and id of **map**. I'm not so sure if the **map** id is what I'm supposed to be using. I've successfully done this before in another app but that time the fragment was added via xml, and not by using replace().

Comment: Are you using Fragment of support package..?

Comment: Nope. I'm developing for API level 11 and up.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `findFragmentById()` method gets a Fragment id out of a container if there actually a Fragment inside it. Otherwise you will get null back.
`findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container)` returns the Fragment inside the `LinearLayout` of your tutorial.

Comment: Here's what I did to solve it: `MyMapFragment = new MAPFragment();    ((com.mypackage.MAPFragment) MyMapFragment).ActivityToMapMethod();`. Your reply does give crucial information to I'm choosing it as an answer. Thanks.

Comment: @user1923613 ,  I don't think creating a `new` instance of your fragment is a good approach.

Answer (score 10):

You should try:

```
this.getId();
```

It worked for me and I hope it works out for you.
Hope it helps! Good Luck!

Comment: I tried this and got back that the id was null. Now what?